# Update GD version to support Webp for PHP 7.3

Tags: php, cpanel, whm

I am trying to enable WebP support for GD through WHM.

Currently I am getting version 2.1.0 (2.5.5 is stable) and when I check PHP info WebP support is not enabled.

Can I enable this using WHM?

I am not experienced with servers and I am using WHM settings.

Answer (score 2):

PHP needs to be compiled to support it.

> To enable support for webp add --with-vpx-dir=DIR . Available as of PHP 5.4.0. As of PHP 7.0.0 --with-webp-dir=DIR has to be added, i.e. support for libvpx has been removed in favor of libwebp.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php

Of course, your server will also need either libvpx or libwebp installed.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately my host tells me that they cannot recompile PHP as we are using cPanel. Is that correct?

Comment: Not so much that they can't, but it's probably a hassle for them. Depends on their infrastructure, but they might have their websites down for a while, or they just want to have a backup for everything before they do this, and the backing up takes a long long time. Option 1: You give up on having it. Option 2: Persevere so long that they decide to do it. Option 3: Change hosting provider.

Comment: I realised that of course, the dependency `libvpx-dev` needs to be added as well (`apt-get install libvpx-dev`) (if you're under php@7.0.0)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of recompiling PHP, you can use the [official WebP package](https://storage.googleapis.com/downloads.webmproject.org/releases/webp/index.html) to generate WebP images. Just download the package depending on your server OS. Extract it and upload it to public_html folder. Using shell_exec command you can generate WebP images from png, jpg etc. No root access or package needs to install. For more information follow the tutorial on [**enable-webp-support-php-7**](https://livtutor.com/enable-webp-support-php-7/). Hope it help.